Reflective Dodecadron
I'm trying to figure out a condensed (ideally, closed form) formula for a potentially nested set of vector reflections with unusual boundary conditions, which I define as follows:
For some real A > 0, I define a reflective rhombic dodecahedron in one of the following (equivalent ways):

The twelve planes $x_i \pm x_j = \pm A$ for $i \neq j$
The 6 vertices $\pm A e_i$ with the 8 vertices $\frac{A}{2} <\pm1, \pm1, \pm1>$

Given a $\vec{v}$ that radiates from the origin, I define $\vec{r}(\vec{v})$ as:
$$     \vec{r}(\vec{v}) = \begin{cases} 
          \vec{v} & \vec{v} \text{ is inside the polytope} \\
          \vec{v} \text{'s reflections at each bounding plane until we've traveled } ||\vec{v}||& \vec{v} \text{ is outside the polytope}  \\
       \end{cases}
$$
QUESTION: I'm looking for a way to express $\vec{r}(\vec{v})$ that doesn't require as many terms as I have reflections: I'm potentially looking at reflecting many, many times. Does such an expression exist, and if so, what is it?
PROGRESS
Individual reflections are essentially trivial to derive. They take on one of the following three forms, for some $a \in {0, 1, 2, 3} $

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & (-1)^a & 0 \\ 
(-1)^a & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix} \vec{v} + \begin{bmatrix} 
0 & -1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}^a
\begin{bmatrix}A \\ A\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$
2.$$\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 & (-1)^a \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
(-1)^a & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix} \vec{v} + \begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 & -1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}^a \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}A \\ A\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$
3.$$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & (-1)^a \\ 
0 & (-1)^a & 0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix} \vec{v} + \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & -1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}^a \begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}A \\ A\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

I also determined that the matrices that multiply $\vec{v}$ and the vector with two A's in it are isomorphic to the group $S_3 \times (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^3$ and that they all have a determinant whose absolute value is 1.
The number of reflections definitely goes up with the magnitude of the vector
A PARTIAL SOLUTION?
One potential pathway I had is the following: suppose w.o.l.g. that the first plane $\vec{v}$ runs into is one of the $|y\pm z| = A$ planes. Change the basis of $\vec{v} = [x, y, z]^T$ to derive $\vec{v}^{*} = [x, y+z, y-z]^T$. Do one dimensional reflections of both $\vec{v}^{*}_2$ and $\vec{v}^{*}_3$ until both coordinates have absolute value less than A, which for a single coordinate $v$ and an $L(v) = \lfloor\frac{v+A}{2A}\rfloor$ has the form $(-1)^L*(v-2AL)$.
From here, it feels like I can do something with just $x$ and the final values for the other two coordinates, without needing to do some kind repetition. My gut wants to tell me that I can do one dimensional reflections of x based on subtracting off the final values of $y \pm z$ from $\pm A$, but I don't actually know if this works.

for the definition of $r$, I don't understand "until we've travelled $||v||$. Do you mean you reflect by the faces until you are inside the polytope?

Suppose we have we have a $\vec{v}$ of length 2. You travel in its direction, and you hit a face when you're at length 1. You reflect by the face you hit, and travel 0.5 units more before hitting another face. You reflect by that face, and travel 0.5 units more after that. Hence, you travelled 1+0.5+0.5 = 2 length units

I'll set $A=1$ for simplicity. You were on the right track. In order to visualize what is going on, I'll propose a reformulation of your problem. You can use your rhombic dodecahedron to tesselate space (rhombic dodecahedral honeycomb). This comes from the fact that the rhombic dodecahedron is the Wigner-Seitz cell of a face-centred cubic lattice. To generate the lattice, you can take as basis vectors:
$$
\begin{align}
a_1 &= (0,1,1) & a_2 &= (1,0,1) & a_3 &= (1,1,0)
\end{align}
$$
Your map consists in finding the correct cell in which the tip of the vector ends up in. The tricky part is that you need to "unfold" (using the 2D analogy) your polyhedra by reflection along its faces, so the orientation of the cells changes. Accounting for orientation, the tessellation is therefore not invariant by translation under the original Bravais lattice generated by $a_1,a_2,a_3$. Instead it is generated by the 6 types of reflections about the planes of equation (which describe the unfolding):
$$
\begin{align}
x\pm y &= 1+2n & y\pm x &= 1+2n & z\pm x &= 1+2n
\end{align}
$$
with $n\in\mathbb Z$. By reflecting along two consecutive planes, you recover a translation, so the group contains a sublattice $\Lambda$, generated by $2a_1,2a_2,2a_3$.
For your map, it means that $r$ is $\Lambda$ periodic. You therefore need only restrict your attention to $v$ taking values in a rhombic dodecahedron twice as large as your original one: the Wigner-Seitz cell of $\Lambda$. It's basically a 3D generalisation of Euclidian division. More generally, you can revert to a primitive cell of $\Lambda$, so the easiest one is the parallelepiped generated by the basis vectors. To get there, you can change into the $2a_1,2a_2,a2_3$ basis and perform Euclidean divisions per component. Depending on where you are, you therefore only need to compute at most three reflections, giving you $8$ possible orientations compatible with doubling of the size of the cell.
To build intuition, here is an illustration of the 2D case for a square domain. The blue arrow is $u$, the red arrow $r(u)$.

Hope this helps.

So the idea is to convert $\vec{v}$ to the basis specified above (where if $A \neq 1$ the $a_i$ have non-zero components $A$?), find the remainder of each component of the vector in the new basis when dividing by 2 (which can be any real number $\in [0, 2)$, convert back, and then do any of the three reflections I need to?
